# Rounding off to NEAREST VALUE WOOCOMMERCE

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, hook-woocommerce

I want to round off to nearest value say if .40  and below  to 00 if .51 and above 1.00.Code used.using latest version of wordpress and woocommerce.Using two decimals by default.it displays cart total up to two decimals.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_price_excluding_tax', 'round_price', 10, 1 );
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_price_including_tax', 'round_price', 10, 1 );
add_filter( 'woocommerce_tax_round', 'round_price', 10, 1);
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_price', 'round_price', 10, 1);

function round_price( $price ){
    // Return rounded price
    return round( $price );
}
```

Comment: The `woocommerce_get_price` hook is now obsolete and deprecated, so instead use `woocommerce_product_get_price` and `woocommerce_product_variation_get_price` *(corresponding to `get_price()` `WC_Product` method)* … Then for `get_regular_price()` and `get_sale_price()` `WC_Product` methods, you can guess related hooks…

Comment: ok thanks.it should work.

Comment: this doesn't round off  cart totals only which i need.......